# How to code reCaptcha to protect email address

Tags: css

I am trying to protect the "mailto" code function on a website from bots and spammers. In other words, I would like to create a button (like "Contact") that on clicking displays an email address, but the code is protected from harvesters.

reCaptcha has been suggested. Can it serve that purpose?

I have been to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ where I created an "account" but I cannot figure out how to use it.

If I am asking the wrong question in the wrong place, please say so. (I am pretty good with HTML and CSS, but reCaptcha has me stumped.)

Comment: It can serve this purpose. Please note that the following is opiniated and it is not the absolute way to do this.


Once reCaptcha is set up in your page, it will basically get you a token.


When a user clicks your "Contact us" button, you send this token to your server, and your server must forward this token to a reCaptcha server for validation. The answer of the reCaptcha server will tell you if this is a robot or not.

If this is not a robot, you can send back to the webpage the email address to be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

sjahan, Thank you.
stackoverflow offers other solutions that I just found here:
[Protect e-mail address with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421948/protect-e-mail-address-with-css-only)

I will start there. But I have bookmarked this page.